# Size of the folder on disk in C# for main folder and then sub folders. Help for sub folders

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable, directoryinfo

I am a newbie in C# world and I am trying to get the size of dis for directory /folders. Below is the code for total size of folder and sub folders together. I want this total size but what I want more is to get the same results for other sub folders in the directory. For example: main Directory/Folder is Fruit and it has sub folders named Orange, Apple, Mango etc. So this code gets total size of Fruit but now I want total size of Orange, Apple, Mango listed separately too.

Please help me fix the code!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users");

        long sizeOfDir = DiskSize(dInfo, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Size on disk in MB : " +
        "{0:N2} MB", ((double)sizeOfDir) / (1024 * 1024));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static long DiskSize(DirectoryInfo dInfo, bool includeSubDir)
    {

        long totalSize = dInfo.EnumerateFiles()
                     .Sum(file => file.Length);


        if (includeSubDir)
        {

            totalSize += dInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
                     .Sum(dir => DiskSize(dir, true));
        }
        return totalSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I have tested. Gives result for each directory.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\temp");

      foreach (DirectoryInfo item in dInfo.EnumerateDirectories()) {

        long sizeOfDir = DiskSize(item, true);


      Console.WriteLine("Size on disk in MB : " +
      "{0:N2} MB", ((double)sizeOfDir) / (1024 * 1024));


      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static long DiskSize(DirectoryInfo dInfo, bool includeSubDir) {

      long totalSize = dInfo.EnumerateFiles()
                   .Sum(file => file.Length);


      if (includeSubDir) {

        totalSize += dInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
                 .Sum(dir => DiskSize(dir, true));
      }
      return totalSize;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Paresh ! Yes it works. I need to display total space of main dir 1st and then the subdivision (like what the above code gives). Now I got one more requirement that I have to display folder names too along with the size. Still your response helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

what about doing the following?

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

long totalSize = 0;
foreach (string name in files)
{
   var info = new FileInfo(name);
   totalSize += info.Length;
}
return totalSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GetDirectories()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and recursively call a function, getting the size on disk for each DirectoryInfo object.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ScanDisksForSize(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ScanDirectoriesForSize(DirectoryInfo topDir)
    {
        long sizeOfDir;
        if (topDir != null)
            sizeOfDir = DiskSize(topDir);
        else
            return;
        Console.WriteLine("Size on disk of {0}: {1:N2} MB", topDir.Name, ((double)sizeOfDir) / (1024 * 1024));

        //Do subfolders

        var subFolders = topDir.GetDirectories();
        if (subFolders == null)
            return;
        foreach (var folder in subFolders)
            ScanDisksForSize(folder);
    }

    static long DiskSize(DirectoryInfo dInfo)
    {
        try
        {   
            long totalSize = dInfo.EnumerateFiles().Sum(file => file.Length);
        return totalSize;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Don't for get to include some error checking.

Comment: Yes you are correct I need to include some error checking.I just need to dive 1 down the folder hierarchy more close to what Paresh replied.